# Following up with Close reason(s) to replace “tech support”

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I was going through the review queue recently and still seeing a lot of tech support close votes which seemed completely on-topic with graphic design and didn't require access to a specific setup or file. Wrzlprmft did a stellar job 10 months ago with the Revisiting closures series. Among the series, the one about tech support seemed to be fairly straight-forward and reaching consensus (as opposed to broad questions for example).

Example [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108802/drag-and-drop-png-files-at-0-0-position-in-photoshop)

So I'm a bit puzzled:
**Do we have any idea as to why tech support close votes on valid questions are still coming in regularly?**

Here is a framework that I like to use when trying to understand/fix behavior-based issues. It could be helpful on reflecting about other issues as well.

[image]

Comment: My hot-take: some users are probably using it as a "super-downvote" rather than a valid close reason, others might see it in the review queue and tack on their close vote because they see it as a low quality question (again close a close vote as a "super-downvote")

Comment: Mods can check the post timeline to see who cast close votes on posts before they are actually closed, so maybe a pattern can be identified and publicly flog— err, privately spoken to

Comment: @JohnB To echo a question I've seen recently but can't seem to trace back: Do we need a flag for close votes? :-)

Comment: @Emilie I feel like that'd just generate noise for mods. If you comment on a question that has been VTCed for an incorrect reason I think it'd be sufficient

Comment: @ZachSaucier It wasn't a serious suggestion :-)